# Continuous Random variable with F_T(u) - Find k, E(T)

Tags: probability, random-variables

A continuous random variable T has the following probability density function:

$$f_T(u)=\begin{cases} 0 & u < 0 \\ 3(1-\frac{u}{k}) & 0 \leq u \leq k \\0 & u \gt k\end{cases}$$

A)Find K:

Given the definition of the probability density function we have:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u) du=1$

$3\int_0^k 1-\frac{u}{k}=1$

$u-\frac{u^2}{2k} \Big\vert_0^k \to 3(k-\frac{k^2}{2k})-0=1$

$k=\frac{2}{3}$

B) Find E[T]

I assume this means finds the expected value of T:

by definition we have:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} uf(u) du$

There are two ways different ways of attacking this from what I can see, I am not sure the correct way, maybe neither. since $k=\frac{2}{3}$ we can replace the upperbound and the value k in the function with $\frac{2}{3}$ or we can just replace k in the function with $\frac{2}{3}$. When I replaced the upperbound k and the value of k in the function with $\frac{2}{3}$ I got one, which is not surprise. The other method:

$3\int_0^k u(1-\frac{3u}{2})$

$3\int_0^k u - \frac{3u^2}{2}$

after integration:

$\frac{u^2}{2}-\frac{3u^3}{6} \vert_0^k \to 3(\frac{k^2}{2}- \frac{3k^3}{6})$

which means $E[T]= \frac{3k^2}{2}-\frac{9k^3}{6}$

which can be reduced to $\frac{3k^2}{2}-\frac{3k^3}{2}$

The above line is the final answer I am given when use the first way I mentioned, replacing k in the function.

However it dawned on me, maybe I can replace all the k's with \frac{2}{3} in my final answer:

Plugging in $\frac{2}{3}: \to \frac{12}{18}-\frac{24}{162}=0.5185185185$

I do not have a firm grasp on this question since I was not in class when this quiz was given so any tips, corrections, and reasoning would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) is correct.

The first method for $B$ is not clearly explained, but it might have overlooked a detail. The second method for B is correct, but fixing the overlook in the first method reaches the solution faster. So, replace $k=2/3$ in the definition of the density function. Then apply the general definition for $E(T)$ to get
$$E(T) = \int_0^{2/3} u \left[3 \left(1 - \frac{3}{2}u \right) \right] du$$
and compute. It seems you forgot the $u$ term before the density in square brackets.